# How can I tell GNU Make that one source file produces multiple outputs?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a program which takes an input `foo.svg` and produces some number of outputs: `foo.0001.png`, `foo.0002.png`, etc. The number of these is deterministic, but not necessarily known at the time the Makefile is written.

I can't find out how to write a Makefile rule for `%.svg` whose effect is

- if there are no `$(basename $<).*.png` in the current directory, run the command
- if there *are* any such, and any of them are older than `$<`, run the command
- otherwise do nothing.

I feel I must be missing something obvious. Can you throw me a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to understand about make is that it doesn't start with the source files and build the output.  It starts with the output, and tries to figure out how that output might be built from files that are available and whether the output is out of date.

So, if you don't know for sure what output you need, for example if the generated output is not deterministic, it's tricky to get make to build things because it's working *backward* from the final result.

What I would recommend is using a "sentinel file" with a known name, to determine the last time the recipe was invoked.  You can add any other outputs as well to get rebuilds to happen.

The second important thing to realize is that automatic variables like $< etc. are only defined *inside* the recipe.  You can't use them outside the recipe (for example in the prerequisites list).  So putting something like `$(basename $<).*.png` into the prerequisites list cannot work because `$<` is empty here.

Putting it all together, maybe something like this will work:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.svg)

SENTINELS := $(SOURCES:%.svg=.sentinel.%)

all: $(SENTINELS)

.sentinel.% : %.svg
        recipe to process $<
        @touch $@
```

(note, untested)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly for normal rules.

For pattern rules, however, it works just fine. A common rule is `%.c %.h: %.y`, for a YACC source being converted to both source and header.

You can do it indirectly for normal rules by inserting a dummy intermediary:

```
out1 out2 out3: dummy
.PHONY: dummy
dummy: input
    cat input
    touch out1 out2 out3
```

When `make` tries to rebuild `out1` etc., it look through `dummy` and see that `input` is newer. When it runs the `dummy` rule, it will update `out1` etc. and when it actually tries to rebuild `out1` etc. it will notice that its timestamp is updated.

A similar technique can be used to prevent re-running expensive rules if one of its dependencies changed timestamp but not content.

Comment: The question states that the files that are generated are not known ahead of time, so this answer does not help.

Comment: You don't actually have to hard-code the output names though; you could use `$(wildcard)`. Beware the case of a formerly-generated output no longer being generated though.

Comment: Wildcard on the _targets_ only helps once you've already built the code one time so you know what the targets are.  How do you know what the targets are _before_ you've built anything?

Comment: This works, but beware: because the rule for `dummy` is outputting build files which aren't declared in the Makefile, then make doesn't know to delete them if the build is interrupted or if the rule fails. This means that if you ^C your build, you can end up with partially generated files in the build tree with timestamps newer than their sources, which will completely screw up your build. (Ask me how I know!)

Comment: @DavidGiven Good point, but you shouldn't be relying on `make` to delete files anyway, since it can crash without any opportunity to do the deletions. Instead it's best to always write to temporary files and then use (individually atomic) renames once the content is settled. This structure should be safe even if `make` crashes in the middle of a sequence of renames, since any file that didn't have a chance to be updated will still show as old and force the rule to re-run next time.